# Casting to byte in C#

Tags: c#, casting, byte

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happens when you cast from short to byte in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575643/what-happens-when-you-cast-from-short-to-byte-in-c)

Can someone explain what's happening when casting a value to a byte, if it's outside the range of min/max byte?  It seems to be taking the integer value and modulo it with 255. I'm trying to understand the reason for why this doesn't throw an exception.

```
int i = 5000;
byte b = (byte)i;

Console.WriteLine(b);  // outputs 136
```

Comment: (modulo 256, just to be clear)

Comment: Because the language spec says so. If you want an exception, you need a `checked` context.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

5000 is represented as 4 bytes (int) 
(hexadecimal)

### |00|00|13|88|

Now, when you convert it to byte, it just takes the last 1-byte.

*Reason: At the IL level, [conv.u1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.conv_u1.aspx) operator will be used which will truncate the high order bits if overflow occurs converting int to byte. (See remarks section in the [conv.u1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.conv_u1.aspx) documentation).*

### |88|

which is 136 in decimal representation

Comment: is it the same as in C++?

Answer (score 5):

What's happening is the system is dropping the Most Significant Bytes in order to make it fit. Look at [this StackOverFlow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575643/what-happens-when-you-cast-from-short-to-byte-in-c) for a pretty good explanation on what's going on.

Comment: I suppose there's no way to check at compile time, and there's a real incentive not to throw exceptions for conversions for base types. Dropping bits seems like the best of a bunch of bad options.

Comment: Well if you don't explicitly cast it, C# should throw you a compile-time error. For example: `byte b = myInt;`...That should throw an error. Now if you explicitly cast it, like in your example above, no error will be thrown

Answer (score 3):

> I'm trying to understand the reason for why this doesn't throw an exception.

Because the default setting for overflow checking is *off*.

Try this, it will throw:

```
checked
{
    int i = 5000;
    byte b = (byte)i;

    Console.WriteLine(b);
}
```

The short form is:

```
int i = 5000;
byte b = checked ( (byte)i );    
Console.WriteLine(b);
```

Answer (score 1):

You get `5000%256 = 136`, like always with overfull.

Answer (score 0):

It is also explained in MSDN. Use **checked()** to throw exception if overflow occurs. Also read this:
[MSDN: Chapter 5: More About Variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/hh127989%28VS.88%29.aspx#Type)